# Can the sort function work for an array with arbitrary numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

I’m trying to get the set of numbers from a function (not included here) to be sorted in ascending order. But the sort function won’t work anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

```
arrayX = [];

array.sort((x,y) => x-y);
```

Comment: function params are c and y, and you are using x and y

Comment: Oh no that’s a mistake. On my system it’s x,y. That’s a typing mistake from my phone

Comment: `not included here` ... the function probably doesn't do what you think it does, hence you're probably sorting an empty array

Comment: You must assign to a new variable to store the result

Comment: Oh no it’s generating an array. But anyway I’ve solved it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are not setting the `arrayX` array equal to the sorted array.

I tried this and it worked for me.

```js
let arr = [51, 12, 34, 63, 26, 84, 13];
let newArr = [];

newArr = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log(newArr);
```

I made up the `arr` array to represent a bunch of random numbers for the test assuming the array you have also contains numbers, this should work.

Comment: Do you understand that arr.sort is an in-place sort? while of course you can assign the result to a new array, in this code `arr` is actually sorted - since it's the same object as `newArr`, and the `=[]` in `let newArr = []` is redundant

Comment: Absolutely! I assumed the reason they included `arrayX` and set it to an empty array was for this purpose. You are absolutely correct. My intentions were to format it the way the given code was.

Comment: all good - I think arrayX in the question was actually the one and only array - but that's my interpretation of a very vague question :p